# C++ pattern for pointer deletion?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, gcc, memory

I was wondering if there was a pattern for the deletion of pointers. More specifically when you need to call some kind of intermediate function for data. Here is a example of what I was thinking:

```cpp
int main() {
    // some code here

    char* return_of_function1 = function1(int_array);
    int return_of_function2 = function2(return_of_function1);
    delete[] return_of_function1;

    // some code here
} 

char* function1(int* int_array) {
    // some code here
}

int function2(char* char_array) {
    // some code here
}
```

```cpp
int main() {
    // some code here

    int return_of_function2 = function2(int_array);

    // some code here
}

char* function1(int* int_array) {
    // some code here
}

int function2(int* int_array) {
    // some code here
    return function2(function1(int_array), true);
}

int function2(char* char_array, bool delete_array) {
    // some code here

    if(delete_array) {
        delete[] char_array;
    }

    return /* return value */;
}
```

The motivation is to avoid intermediate calls for data on properties of a set. Again, I'm just asking if this is commonly used, or even a good idea to begin with.

Thanks so much.

Comment: If you want a pattern, RAII is a good one. It requires wrapping your pointer  in a class so that it can automatically allocate and delete for you. However, this is common to the point that `std::unique_ptr` exists. I'd still take a bit of time to read up on RAII, though.

Comment: None of that is commonly used, or a good idea. Use smart pointers.

Comment: If you want a run time sized array, `std::vector` is you RAII container of choice.  It'll manage the memory for you.

Comment: The best pattern is to not use new or delete unless you are forced by an academic requirement. Instead use one of the containers in the standard library or a smart pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general practice is to move away from raw pointers the way you're using them. If your char * is really a string, then use std::string, for instance.

RAII stands for Resource Acquisition is Initialization. What matters for this is that you wrap your resources with an object, and you let the object go out of scope. It'll get destroyed by falling out of scope, and the destructor is the only place that you have to worry about destroying your data. If you really are going to use a char * and it's not really a string, and thus you should use string, it might look like this:

```
class CharArray {
public:
     CharArray(whatever args you need);
     virtual ~CharArray() { if (ptr) delete[] ptr; }
private:
     char * ptr = nullptr;
};
```

If any methods of CharArray actually can change ptr, then you would want to make sure you carefully free the old contents first.

You would also want to make sure you have the full complement of move constructors / operators, etc, so you can safely return this.

The other choice is smart pointers. See `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr`. These guys are great. They handle all this for you, with reference counting.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` doesn't have reference counting.  Also, if they have char data that isn't a string, `std::vector<char>` is a suitable replacement for `std::string`.

Comment: 1) `if (ptr)` in destructor is useless. `delete` is a noop when `ptr` is nullptr, anyway. 2) What about copies of `CharArray`? Wouldn't it cause UB, if any copy of the instance of such class, is made?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I am demonstrating the basic idea, not providing a 200-line complete implementation.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Regarding "2)" there is the passage *"You would also want to make sure you have the full complement of move constructors / operators, etc, so you can safely return this."* addressing that, though a link to the rule of 3/5/0 wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @JosephLarson "_I am demonstrating the basic idea, not providing a 200-line complete implementation._" 1) Non-needed constructs in the code (`if (ptr)`) increase the length of the example, not decrease it. 2) I wasn't asking for complete implementation. I just see the danger of person seeing code example, copying it over, and being suprised that it fails under some conditions, as simple, as being copied.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Sure, I saw that, but default copy constructor, doesn't change `ptr`. So, I thought, that it didn't apply in that case.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Sorry, I carelessly copied the wrong sentence. I edited my comment with the correct quote.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I missed that, thank you. Yes, that would address my second point.